# Class methods (ruby)

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, class-method

Newbie here, having a hard time understanding Class methods and why I cannot get an attribute to show up correctly in the instance.

```
class Animal
  attr_accessor :noise, :color, :legs, :arms

  def self.create_with_attributes(noise, color)
    animal = self.new(noise)
    @noise = noise
    @color = color
    return animal
  end

  def initialize(noise, legs=4, arms=0)
    @noise = noise
    @legs = legs
    @arms = arms
    puts "----A new animal has been instantiated.----"
  end
end

animal1 = Animal.new("Moo!", 4, 0)
puts animal1.noise
animal1.color = "black"
puts animal1.color
puts animal1.legs
puts animal1.arms
puts

animal2 = Animal.create_with_attributes("Quack", "white")
puts animal2.noise
puts animal2.color
```

When I use the class method `create_with_attributes` (on animal.2), I expect `"white"` to appear when I `puts animal2.color`.

It seems as though I have defined it using `attr_accessor` just like I have "noise", and yet noise appears correctly while color will not. I do not get an error when I run this program, but the .color attribute is just not appearing. I believe it is because I have somehow labeled it incorrectly in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.create_with_attributes` is a class method, so setting `@noise` and `@color` within it is *not* setting an instance variable, but instead what's known as a [class instance variable](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ClassInstanceVariable.html).

What you want to do is set the variables on the instance you've just created, so instead, change `self.create_with_attributes` to look something like:

```
 def self.create_with_attributes(noise, color)
     animal = self.new(noise)
     animal.noise = noise
     animal.color = color
     animal
 end
```

which will set the attributes on your new instance, instead of on the class itself.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I was banging my head against the wall and you made it very clear for me. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, than the reason the noise attribute was appearing in animal.2 is because I had set it in the Initialize method, which was setting the instance variable?

Comment: Right. Because your `initialize` method requires the noise, the `animal.noise = noise` line in `self.create_with_attributes` isn't actually necessary, as it will already be set.

Comment: I know this is a very beginner question, but can you explain the significance of putting `return animal` in the `self.create_with.attributes method`? What is this actually doing?

Comment: Sure. In Ruby, everything is an expression, and expressions return the last thing that was evaluated in them automatically. Having an explicit return at the end of a method doesn't break anything, but is redundant, because a method will already return the last expression that was evaluated within it. You *do* need an explicit `return` in the case you want to return from a method early, but otherwise is considered 'unrubyish'. Take a look at a contrived example I put up at https://gist.github.com/a29e73325cd42eaeb16d which may help a bit.

Answer (score 1):

When you're in the `create_with_attributes` method, the instance variables are set on the `Animal` class itself, not on the instance of `Animal` you've just created. This is because the method is on the `Animal` class (which is an instance of `Class`), and thus it is run within that context, not the context of any instance of `Animal`. If you do:

```
Animal.instance_variable_get(:@color)
```

after running the method like you describe, you should get `"white"` back.

That said, you need to instead set the attributes on the instance you've just created by calling the setter methods like so:

```
def self.create_with_attributes(noise, color)
  animal = self.new(noise)
  animal.color = color
  return animal
end
```

I removed the setting of `noise` since it's done in your `initialize` anyway.

Comment: Thanks for adding the very last note about removing the setting of "noise". That made it very clear to me what was going on.