# class methosd (ruby)

Tags: ruby, class-method

Can you tell me why this isn't working?

The code below outputs student1 & student2 properly, but I cannot get the class method to work on student3.

All I am trying to do is assign a class method `.create_with_species` , with the species attribute = to "Human".

However, when I run the program, I get an error that "local variable or method `sex` is undefined". I'm a newbie and I can't figure out what I've done wrong!

It was my understanding that since I had identified "sex" in the Initialize method I should be able to use it within a class method such as `create_with_species`. I tried explicitly defining sex in the class method, as `student.sex = sex`, but still got the same error.

```
class Students

  attr_accessor :sex, :age, :species

  def self.create_with_species(species)
    student = Students.new(sex,age)
    student.species = species
    return student
  end

  def initialize(sex, age)
    @sex = sex
    @age = age
    puts "----A new student has been added----"
  end

end

student1 = Students.new("Male", "21")
puts student1.sex
puts student1.age
puts

student2 = Students.new("Female", "19")
puts student2.sex
puts student2.age

student3 = Students.create_with_species("human")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sex` and `age` are not defined.  Do you mean to use a class variable?  Using `@age` or `@sex` will result in nils, as no class attributes are set and the instance is not yet created, hence no instance variables set either.  You don't need to state `Students.new` in `create_with_species`.  `new` will suffice because you are scoped in `Students`.  I think you would be better off passing a hash object to initialize, and just set the species variable there.  It will be nil if not assigned explicitly, or you can have a default value.

Try this:

```
class Students

  attr_accessor :sex, :age, :species

  def initialize(options)
    @sex = options[:sex]
    @age = options[:age]
    @species = options[:species]
    puts "----A new student has been added----"
  end

end

student1 = Students.new(:sex => "Male", :age => "21")
puts student1.sex
puts student1.age
puts student1.species
puts

student2 = Students.new(:sex => "Female", :age => "19")
puts student2.sex
puts student2.age

student3 = Students.new(
    :sex => "Hermi", :age => "2", :species => "alien"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as the syntax goes, you have to use `@sex` and `@age` instead of `sex` and `age`. Otherwise they won't be interpreted as instance attributes.

But you do realize that the logic of the code is broken? I understand you want to use the static factory method pattern but this is not how you should do it since `@sex`and `@age` are nil when you call that method and those variables are instance attributes not class attributes.

Answer (score 1):

`@sex` and `@age` are instance attributes. You can't use them (what would they mean?) inside a class method. You've written just `sex` and `age` inside `create_with_species`, but again: what are these supposed to refer to? (In an instance method they'd be calls to the accessors, but at this point there's no instance to call the accessors on.)

Consider: when you say

```
student3 = Students.create_with_species("human")
```

what `sex` and `age` should this new student object get? You haven't specified any.

Comment: Thank You, I got it to work. However, now I have a problem. Look at the answer I accepted to the question below. That guy made a class method which (based on your explanation), shouldn't work...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366572/class-methods-ruby

Comment: I don't understand why you think it shouldn't work. That class method gets the things it needs as arguments, and then sets them on a particular instance.